golang etcd grpc Call Route err: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service kkk.Simple
I have two grpc services, one is called simple_grpc in the etcd-example project, the other is called shop_grpc in the shop-example project, and the client project is in etcd-example-client. When I start the two services and register them into etcd. Appears when the client calls the service.
Call Route err: rpc error:
 code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service kkk.Simple

etcd-example project：
package etcdv3

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    clientv3 "go.etcd.io/etcd/client/v3"
)

type ServiceRegister struct {
    cli           *clientv3.Client
    leaseID       clientv3.LeaseID
    keepAliveChan <-chan *clientv3.LeaseKeepAliveResponse
    key           string
    val           string
}

func NewServiceRegister(endpoints []string, serName, addr string, lease int64) (*ServiceRegister, error) {
    cli, err := clientv3.New(clientv3.Config{
        Endpoints:   endpoints,
        DialTimeout: 60 * time.Second,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ser := &ServiceRegister{
        cli: cli,
        key: "/shop/" + serName,
        val: addr,
    }

    if err := ser.putKeyWithLease(lease); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return ser, nil
}

func (s *ServiceRegister) putKeyWithLease(lease int64) error {
    resp, err := s.cli.Grant(context.Background(), lease)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err = s.cli.Put(context.Background(), s.key, s.val, clientv3.WithLease(resp.ID))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    leaseRespChan, err := s.cli.KeepAlive(context.Background(), resp.ID)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    s.leaseID = resp.ID

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case _, ok := <-leaseRespChan:
                if !ok {
                    fmt.Println("etcd keepalive channel closed")
                } else {
                    goto END
                }
            }
        END:
            time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }()
    log.Printf("Put key:%s  val:%s  success!", s.key, s.val)
    return nil
}

func (s *ServiceRegister) Close() error {
    if _, err := s.cli.Revoke(context.Background(), s.leaseID); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    log.Println("撤销租约")
    return s.cli.Close()
}


package kkk;
option go_package = "etcd-example/grpclb/proto/abc";
message SimpleRequest{
    string data = 1;
}

message SimpleResponse{
    int32 code = 1;
    string value = 2;
}

service Simple{
    rpc Route (SimpleRequest) returns (SimpleResponse){};
}

package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"

    "etcd-example/grpclb/etcdv3"
    pb "etcd-example/grpclb/proto"
)


type SimpleService struct {
    pb.UnimplementedSimpleServer
}

const (
    Address string = "192.168.60.246:8001"
    Network string = "tcp"
    SerName string = "simple_grpc"
)

var EtcdEndpoints = []string{"localhost:2379"}

func main() {
    listener, err := net.Listen(Network, Address)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("net.Listen err: %v", err)
    }
    log.Println(Address + " net.Listing...")
    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterSimpleServer(grpcServer, &SimpleService{})
    ser, err := etcdv3.NewServiceRegister(EtcdEndpoints, SerName, Address, 60)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("register service err: %v", err)
    }
    defer ser.Close()
    err = grpcServer.Serve(listener)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("grpcServer.Serve err: %v", err)
    }
}

func (s *SimpleService) Route(ctx context.Context, req *pb.SimpleRequest) (*pb.SimpleResponse, error) {
    log.Println("receive: " + req.Data)
    res := pb.SimpleResponse{
        Code:  200,
        Value: "hello " + req.Data,
    }
    return &res, nil
}


shop-example project：
package etcdv3

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    clientv3 "go.etcd.io/etcd/client/v3"
)

// ServiceRegister 创建租约注册服务
type ServiceRegister struct {
    cli     *clientv3.Client // etcd client
    leaseID clientv3.LeaseID // 租约ID
    // 租约keepalieve相应chan
    keepAliveChan <-chan *clientv3.LeaseKeepAliveResponse
    key           string // key
    val           string // value
}

// NewServiceRegister 新建注册服务
func NewServiceRegister(endpoints []string, serName, addr string, lease int64) (*ServiceRegister, error) {
    cli, err := clientv3.New(clientv3.Config{
        Endpoints:   endpoints,
        DialTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ser := &ServiceRegister{
        cli: cli,
        key: "/shop/" + serName,
        val: addr,
    }

    // 申请租约设置时间keepalive
    if err := ser.putKeyWithLease(lease); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return ser, nil
}

// 设置租约
func (s *ServiceRegister) putKeyWithLease(lease int64) error {
    // 设置租约时间
    resp, err := s.cli.Grant(context.Background(), lease)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // 注册服务并绑定租约
    _, err = s.cli.Put(context.Background(), s.key, s.val, clientv3.WithLease(resp.ID))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // 设置续租 定期发送需求请求
    leaseRespChan, err := s.cli.KeepAlive(context.Background(), resp.ID)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    s.leaseID = resp.ID

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case _, ok := <-leaseRespChan:
                if !ok {
                    fmt.Println("etcd keepalive channel closed")
                } else {
                    goto END
                }
            }
        END:
            time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }()
    // s.keepAliveChan = leaseRespChan
    log.Printf("Put key:%s  val:%s  success!", s.key, s.val)
    return nil
}

// ListenLeaseRespChan 监听 续租情况
func (s *ServiceRegister) ListenLeaseRespChan() {
    for leaseKeepResp := range s.keepAliveChan {
        log.Println("续约成功", leaseKeepResp)
    }
    log.Println("关闭续租")
}

// Close 注销服务
func (s *ServiceRegister) Close() error {
    // 撤销租约
    if _, err := s.cli.Revoke(context.Background(), s.leaseID); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    log.Println("撤销租约")
    return s.cli.Close()
}


syntax = "proto3";

package shop;
option go_package = "shop-example/grpclb/proto/fff";
message SimpleRequest{
    string data = 1;
}

message SimpleResponse{
    int32 code = 1;
    string value = 2;
}

service Simple{
    rpc AAA(SimpleRequest) returns (SimpleResponse){};
}

package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"

    "shop-example/grpclb/etcdv3"
    fff "shop-example/grpclb/proto"
)

type LiveService struct {
    fff.UnimplementedSimpleServer
}

const (
    Address string = "192.168.60.246:9001"
    Network string = "tcp"
    SerName string = "shop.Simple"
)

var EtcdEndpoints = []string{"localhost:2379"}

func main() {
    listener, err := net.Listen(Network, Address)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("net.Listen err: %v", err)
    }
    log.Println(Address + " net.Listing...")
    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
    fff.RegisterSimpleServer(grpcServer, &LiveService{})
    ser, err := etcdv3.NewServiceRegister(EtcdEndpoints, SerName, Address, 1000)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("register service err: %v", err)
    }
    defer ser.Close()
    err = grpcServer.Serve(listener)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("grpcServer.Serve err: %v", err)
    }
}

func (s *LiveService) AAA(ctx context.Context, req *fff.SimpleRequest) (*fff.SimpleResponse, error) {
    log.Println("liveService receive: " + req.Data)
    res := fff.SimpleResponse{
        Code:  200,
        Value: "hello " + req.Data,
    }
    return &res, nil
}



etcd-example-client
syntax = "proto3";

package shop;
option go_package = "shop-example/grpclb/proto/fff";
message SimpleRequest{
    string data = 1;
}

message SimpleResponse{
    int32 code = 1;
    string value = 2;
}

service Simple{
    rpc AAA(SimpleRequest) returns (SimpleResponse){};
}

package etcdv3

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "go.etcd.io/etcd/api/v3/mvccpb"
    clientv3 "go.etcd.io/etcd/client/v3"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/resolver"
)

const schema = "shop"

// ServiceDiscovery 服务发现
type ServiceDiscovery struct {
    cli        *clientv3.Client // etcd client
    cc         resolver.ClientConn
    serverList sync.Map // 服务列表
}

// NewServiceDiscovery  新建发现服务
func NewServiceDiscovery(endpoints []string) resolver.Builder {
    cli, err := clientv3.New(clientv3.Config{
        Endpoints:   endpoints,
        DialTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return &ServiceDiscovery{
        cli: cli,
    }
}

// Build 为给定目标创建一个新的`resolver`，当调用`grpc.Dial()`时执行
func (s *ServiceDiscovery) Build(target resolver.Target, cc resolver.ClientConn, opts resolver.BuildOptions) (resolver.Resolver, error) {
    log.Println("Build")
    s.cc = cc
    // Call the function to get the actual endpoint string
    // endpoint := target.Endpoint() // Call the function here
    // prefix := "/live/" + endpoint + "/"
    // a := target.URL

    // a.Path
    // fmt.Println(a.Path)
    prefix := "/shop/"
    // 根据前缀获取现有的key
    resp, err := s.cli.Get(context.Background(), prefix, clientv3.WithPrefix())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    for _, ev := range resp.Kvs {
        s.SetServiceList(string(ev.Key), string(ev.Value))
    }
    s.cc.UpdateState(resolver.State{Addresses: s.getServices()})
    // 监视前缀，修改变更的server
    go s.watcher(prefix)
    return s, nil
}

// ResolveNow 监视目标更新
func (s *ServiceDiscovery) ResolveNow(rn resolver.ResolveNowOptions) {
    log.Println("ResolveNow")
}

// Scheme return schema
func (s *ServiceDiscovery) Scheme() string {
    return schema
}

// Close 关闭
func (s *ServiceDiscovery) Close() {
    log.Println("Close")
    s.cli.Close()
}

// watcher 监听前缀
func (s *ServiceDiscovery) watcher(prefix string) {
    rch := s.cli.Watch(context.Background(), prefix, clientv3.WithPrefix())
    log.Printf("watching prefix:%s now...", prefix)
    for wresp := range rch {
        for _, ev := range wresp.Events {
            switch ev.Type {
            case mvccpb.PUT: // 新增或修改
                s.SetServiceList(string(ev.Kv.Key), string(ev.Kv.Value))
            case mvccpb.DELETE: // 删除
                s.DelServiceList(string(ev.Kv.Key))
            }
        }
    }
}

// SetServiceList 新增服务地址
func (s *ServiceDiscovery) SetServiceList(key, val string) {
    s.serverList.Store(key, resolver.Address{Addr: val})
    s.cc.UpdateState(resolver.State{Addresses: s.getServices()})
    log.Println("put key :", key, "val:", val)
}

// DelServiceList 删除服务地址
func (s *ServiceDiscovery) DelServiceList(key string) {
    s.serverList.Delete(key)
    s.cc.UpdateState(resolver.State{Addresses: s.getServices()})
    log.Println("del key:", key)
}

// GetServices 获取服务地址
func (s *ServiceDiscovery) getServices() []resolver.Address {
    addrs := make([]resolver.Address, 0, 10)
    s.serverList.Range(func(k, v interface{}) bool {
        addrs = append(addrs, v.(resolver.Address))
        return true
    })
    return addrs
}


package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/resolver"

    "etcd-example/grpclb/etcdv3"
    pb "etcd-example/grpclb/proto"

    live "etcd-example/grpclb/proto/live"
)

var (
    // EtcdEndpoints etcd地址
    EtcdEndpoints = []string{"localhost:2379"}
    // SerName 服务名称
    SerName       = "kkk.Simple"
    grpcClient    pb.SimpleClient
    shopRpcClient live.SimpleClient
)

func main() {
    r := etcdv3.NewServiceDiscovery(EtcdEndpoints)
    resolver.Register(r)
    // 连接服务器
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(
        fmt.Sprintf("%s:///%s", "shop", SerName),
        grpc.WithDefaultServiceConfig(`{"loadBalancingConfig": [{"round_robin":{}}]}`),
        grpc.WithInsecure(),
    )
    // conn, err := grpc.Dial(
    //  fmt.Sprintf("192.168.60.246:8001"),
    //  grpc.WithDefaultServiceConfig(`{"loadBalancingConfig": [{"round_robin":{}}]}`),
    //  grpc.WithInsecure(),
    // )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("net.Connect err: %v", err)
    }

    defer conn.Close()

    conn1, err := grpc.Dial(
        fmt.Sprintf("%s:///%s", "shop", "shop.Simple"),
        grpc.WithDefaultServiceConfig(`{"loadBalancingConfig": [{"round_robin":{}}]}`),
        grpc.WithInsecure(),
    )

    grpcClient = pb.NewSimpleClient(conn)
    shopRpcClient = live.NewSimpleClient(conn1)
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        route(i)
        route1(i)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }

}

func route(i int) {
    req := pb.SimpleRequest{
        Data: "grpc " + strconv.Itoa(i),
    }

    res, err := grpcClient.Route(context.Background(), &req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Call Route err: %v", err)
    }
    log.Println(res)
}

func route1(i int) {
    req := live.SimpleRequest{
        Data: "grpc1 " + strconv.Itoa(i),
    }

    res, err := shopRpcClient.AAA(context.Background(), &req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Call Route err: %v", err)
    }
    log.Println(res)
}



Your code is invalid, for example the Go import path is locally specified in a .proto file by declaring a go_package option with the full import path. You are using a relative path "./fff".

@eik According to what you said, the above code has been changed, but the same error still occurs.

I still believe you need to clean up and produce a minimal reproducible example. You have the same protocol buffer definition three times, once in a different package.

The grpc.Resolver interface in your code is implemented by etcdv3.ServiceDiscovery struct. The resolver should produce a list of endpoints for a given resolver.Target. In your code however, you've hardcoded the prefix := "/shop/" instead of parsing it from the target string. As a result, the resolver produces the same set of addresses for all targets. What seems to be happening here is that the request made by both conn and conn1 are going to the server running shop.Simple and not kkk.Simple. So requests from conn reach the wrong server and gRPC can't find a service with name kkk.Simple registered.
To fix this, you need to ensure that etcdv3.ServiceDiscovery produces the correct list of endpoints for each target.
